# Show only current and future months in a Select element if current year was chosen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a form for a credit card payment. 
As part of the form, I also collect the expiration date details of the client's card.

The month and year fields are both of a Select element type within the HTML.

What I want to do, using jQuery or JavaScript, is, in case the client chooses current year from the list of available years, previous months will be removed from the list of options, and if a past month was already selected, the value in the month field should reset by default to be current month selected.
In case he changes the year value again to a future year, all months should be shown again.

Basically what I'm trying to achieve here is, making sure the client can't choose a past date for a CC expiry date, instead of using validations and showing alerts in case he does.

**EDIT**

Well, I haven't tried anything yet as I'm not experienced much with front-end, but I assume I will have to use something like:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#year").change(function () {
            var date = new Date();
            var currentmonth = date.getMonth();
            var currentyear = date.getFullYear();
            var year = $(this).val();
            if (year == currentyear) {
                $("#month").html('add a loop here to add options from currentMonth to 12');
            } else {
                $("#month").html('same as above but from 1 to 12');
            }
        });
    });
```

I'm just not sure if it's the right way to do it and if so, how to write the loop properly. Also, I don't know if I'm missing something in order for it to work.

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: Let them choose the year first, or just let them choose a year and month and show some green checkmark if everything is okay, so it's not obtrusive.  B.t.w., usually credit card payments are handled by external payment providers. Are you sure you need this input at all?

Comment: @j08691 Thanks for your comment. Edited the original post to show what I think of doing.

Comment: @GolezTrol When using Silent Post method with some of the payment providers, you do have to collect these details on your side and pass it securely using synchronous transaction processing method. Anyway, I edited the original post, to show what I assume can be done. Any feedback will be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I did eventually:

- PHP (using Laravel framework), HTML and jQuery *

First of all I created an array of all month names starting from index 1 and on. ([1]=>January, [2]=>February, ...) => $months

I also saved the int value of the current as $currentMonth

HTML:

```
<select id="year" name="..." class="...">
    <option value="">Choose...</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
    <option value="2019">2019</option>
    <option value="2020">2020</option>
    <option value="2021">2021</option>
    <option value="2022">2022</option>
    <option value="2023">2023</option>
    <option value="2024">2024</option>
    <option value="2025">2025</option>
    <option value="2026">2026</option>
    <option value="2027">2027</option>
    <option value="2028">2028</option>
    <option value="2029">2029</option>
    <option value="2030">2030</option>
</select>



<select id="month" name="..." class="...">
    <option value="">Choose</option>
    <option value="1">January</option>
    <option value="2">February</option>
    <option value="3">March</option>
    <option value="4">April</option>
    <option value="5">May</option>
    <option value="6">June</option>
    <option value="7">July</option>
    <option value="8">August</option>
    <option value="9">September</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#year").change(function () {
    var date = new Date();
    var currentyear = date.getFullYear();
    var year = $(this).val();
    if (year == currentyear) {
        $("#month").html("@for($i=(int)$currentMonth;$i<=12;$i++)<option value='{{$i}}'>$months[$i]</option>@endfor");
    } else {
        $("#month").html("@for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++)<option value='{{$i}}'>$months[$i]</option>@endfor");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you were having trouble with, but here's an example of what you could do: (Untested)

```
// get current date
var now = new Date();
var day = now.getDate(); // day of the month
var month = now.getMonth()+1; // this is normally 0-based, added 1 for 1-based months
var year = now.getFullYear(); // four digit year

// compare user date to current date
if(year === userYear){
  if(userMonth<=month){
    userMonth = month;
    if(userDay<day){
      userDay = day;
    }
  }
  for(var i=0;i<month;i++){ // remove all months before current month
    monthArray.remove(i);
  }
} else {
  // reset the array
  for(var i in monthArray){
    monthArray.remove(i); // remove all the elements
  }
  for(var i=1;i<13;i++){
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = i;
    x.add(option); // add all the months
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will try it out shortly and will let you know

Comment: @Raze I have a similar problem. Did this work for you?

Comment: @RicardoAndres I had several issues implementing it this way. I will post another answer here with what I've done eventually.